# Using basic sed in bash script

Tags: bash, sed

I'm sure this is quite simple. However, it's just not working for me. What stupid thing am I doing wrong please? I am running the following shell script like this:

```
bash test1.sh
```

Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
bluesman_a="Magic Slim"
bluesman_b=($echo "$bluesman_a" | sed "/s/Slim/Sam/")
echo $bluesman_b
```

I get:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `|'
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: You have a typo, there shouldn't be a leading `/` before `s` and the syntax should be `$(echo ..)`. i.e. `bluesman_b=$(echo "$bluesman_a" | sed "s/Slim/Sam/")`

Comment: yes, sorry that shouldn't be there. It's not there in the code I run. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew that works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `"$(...)"` to wrap a command to assign the output to a variable and you need to remove the first `/` in the `sed` replacement command. Also, you do not need to use `echo` to pass a variable to `sed`.

```
bluesman_b="$(sed 's/Slim/Sam/' <<< "$bluesman_a")"
```

Or, to replace `Slim` with `Sam` just once, use

```
bluesman_b="${bluesman_a/Slim/Sam}"
```

See [10.1. Manipulating Strings](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).

See the [online Bash demo](https://ideone.com/fAwT8J)

Comment: Both work a treat, thanks. Thought I'd been following online advice/tutorials fine(!). Obviously something awry with advice, or me.

Comment: You usually want to use `sed` when there are more than one replacements necessary, or when the pattern is complex. For a simple single literal substring replacement, string manipulation operation is enough.